How to properly implement async/await in a method with a long-running task?
I am working on a C# application where I need to perform a long-running task (e.g., querying a database or calling an external API). I want to use async/await to ensure my application remains responsive, but I am unsure if my implementation is correct. Here's the method I have so far:
My code is below, what I am trying to do?
public async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
{
    // Simulating a long-running task
    string result = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // Simulate work
        return "Data retrieved";
    });

    return result;
}

Is using Task.Run here the best practice, or should I handle this differently?
Should I avoid Thread.Sleep in such scenarios? What is a better way to simulate a delay in async methods for testing purposes?
Are there any potential issues with exception handling in this implementation?

Calling the database or API isn't long-running, unless it's so long it risks a timeout. For really long running tasks use a BackgroundService

In the folllowing, a Non-CPU-Bound aync call is assumed.
Original code:
public async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
{
    // Simulating a long-running task
    string result = await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // Simulate work
        return "Data retrieved";
    });

    return result;
}

can be improved like so:
public async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
{
    // Simulating a long-running task
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    return "Data retrieved";
}


do not use Thread.Sleep in async code unless it's absolutely intentional, you know what you are doing and why and you actually want the resulting behavior and sideeffects. It blocks the current thread. Which is different from executing async I/O (ike calling an API).

You do not need to Task.Run here. Just await Task.Delay should be enough in most cases (again: given you are "simulating" IO).


BTW: As you can see in the example, I like to use the overload of Delay that takes a TimeSpan. It is a little longer to type but IMHO simply more convenient to read, especially when the milliseconds exceed a certain number. So, while it's not a "must", I'd still recommend it.

EDIT:
Anticipating you are going to replace this later on by an actual API call, chances are it supports cancellation. So you may want to prepare for that like so:
public async Task<string> GetDataAsync(CancellationToken cancel = default)
{
    // Simulating a long-running task
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), cancel);
    return "Data retrieved";
}


Agree on using Timespan.  No ambiguity.

You code basically represents "async over sync"; meaning - you've taken a synchronous operation, and you're using Task.Run to pretend that it is async. This sort of works in that it moves the CPU blockage out from where it will get in your way, but it is an anti-pattern: you have solved the wrong problem. The real problem isn't that you could see the CPU blockage; the problem is that there is a CPU blockage.
The fix for that is: switch to async-based code for the actual work. Then you don't need to use Task.Run. Most modern database or other client-something libraries have full support for async code, and often (not quite always), this basically means "add Async to the end of some methods, and await before them"; for example, if your old pre-Task.Run code was:
public string GetData()
{
    var args = PrepareArgs();
    var rows = db.ExecuteSomeProc(args);
    return PostProcess(rows);
}

then your new shiny code might be as simple as:
public async Task<string> GetDataAsync()
{
    var args = PrepareArgs();
    var rows = await db.ExecuteSomeProcAsync(args);
    return PostProcess(rows);
}

Obviously there's more to it than that, but: that's the super-high-level overview.

We usually treat IO bound task differently from Compute bound tasks.
Databases and webrequests are typical examples of IO bound tasks. These usually have an async API, like HttpClient.GetStringAsync or .ToListAsync() that return a task, and in that case you simply await the task. No need for Task.Run.
Sorting a very large list would be an example of a compute bound task. These inherently block the thread, so to keep the UI responsive you need to move the execution to a background thread, typically using Task.Run:
public async Task<string> GetDataAsync(){
    var data = await Task.Run(()=> MyComputeBoundMethod());
    // do any post processing of the data that needs to be done on the UI thread.
    // If no post processing is needed you can just return the task
    return data;
}

There are some cases where this simple approach need to be adjusted. Not all third party libraries expose an async API for IO bound tasks. Some libraries do have an async API, but still block. Some tasks are a mix of IO and compute.
Also keep in mind the user experience of these background tasks. It is often a good idea to show a progress-bar when possible, and/or a cancel button. You may also want to prevent the user from doing things in an incorrect order, say clicking on the GetData-button a second time before the first call has completed. A fairly simple approach is to show a modal dialog while the background task is in progress, thereby preventing any other user input than cancelling the task.

Should I avoid Thread.Sleep in such scenarios?

Thread.Sleep can be used for testing, but should be avoided in any production code. It would be used to simulate compute bound work, but it has some limitations since it does not actually cause any CPU load, So it is best to use actual work when possible.

What is a better way to simulate a delay in async methods for testing purposes?

Task.Delay() is the typical way to simulate an async task. But again, use real work when feasible, since it can help reveal some potential problems.

Are there any potential issues with exception handling in this implementation?

The typical rules are:

await all tasks
return a Task whenever possible
handle any exceptions when returning a task is not possible (i.e. in an event handler)

So the posted example is fine in this regard.
